# Citations showing wrong

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing a paper and when citing sources I get the following:
[image]

this is the code for that result:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\usepackage{apacite}



\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

text \cite{greenwade93}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

with .bib file:

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
```

How do I make the citations show correctly? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I don't think the apalike style is meant to be used with the apacite backage. If you want to use the apacite package you should use the apacite style or one of the other styles mentioned in [its documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf). Or if you want to use apalike, you should leave out apacite (and maybe use natbib instead)? Or switch to biblatex-apa as TRK suggests.

Comment: Write `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

Answer (score 4):

The `apalike` bibliography style is positively ancient -- think 1984 or thereabouts.

Since you're using the [apacite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) citation management package, you really ought to be using the `apacite`, not the `apalike`, bibliography style. Taken together, the `apacite` citation management package and `apacite` bibliography style implement the formatting guidelines of the **6th edition** of the "APA manual".

Do note that the 6th ed. is no longer the most recent edition of the APA manual. If you need to format the citation call-outs and the bibliographic entries according the current, i.e., **7th edition** of the APA manual, you'll have to switch from BibTeX and the `apacite` combo to `biber` and the `biblatex` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {Comprehensive TeX Archive Network} ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl} %%% [hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%%\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

%% if ok to use 6th ed. of APA manual. Must use BiBTeX:
%\usepackage{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{apacite} %%{apalike}

% if ok with using biblatex with either 6th or 7th ed. of APA manual, Must use biber.
%\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex} % 6th ed.
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}   % 7th ed.
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{greenwade93}

% if using 'apacite' (and bibtex):
%\bibliography{sample}

% if using biblatex (and biber):
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code a bit.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
%\usepackage{apacite} % commented this
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex} % use biblatex
\addbibresource{sample.bib} % specify the name of the bib file


\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

text \parencite{greenwade93} % parencite instead of cite

%\bibliographystyle{apalike} % commented this out
\printbibliography % used printbibliography command
%\bibliography{sample} % commented this out

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that this probably requires using biber instead of biblatex to create the bibliography.

Comment: @frabjous It seems to be working for me on Overleaf :)

Comment: @frabjous I am sorry, but I don't understand the nuances of LaTeX well enough to be able to see the point that you might be alluding to.

Comment: Bibliographies are created by running a separate program from latex, but bibtex and biber are two different programs. Overleaf does all this for you, and is smart enough to know whether to run bibtex or biber, but if you were doing this in your own computer, depending on your tooling, you might need to know which program to run.

Comment: If the option `style=apa` is set, the options `sortcites=true` and `sorting=nyt` are redundant.

Comment: Technically speaking the `sorting=nyt,` is not redundant. It is a *very* bad idea. `sorting=nyt,` will set the standard name-year-title sorting and overwrite the special APA-compliant sorting scheme that `style=apa,` sets automatically. Remove both `sortcites=true,` and `sorting=nyt,`.